# How to select numbers from another font?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

How can I change the numbers of the text font with the math  font numbers and the other way around using XeLaTeX?

Comment: Can you provide a basic example?

Comment: As I understand your question, you want to use numbers from the same font in both text and math environments. Won't you get that by just using the same font everywhere?

Comment: You could use siunitx for the numbers, it uses the mathrm font by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving (say)

```
\setromanfont{Bitstream Charter} 
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num}]{Courier New}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Bitstream Charter}
```

This will produce numbers in Bitstream Charter font in normal text
and Courier New font numbers in Math mode.